# Django error when removing ForeignKey relationship

Tags: python, django

I have a class as following:

```
class Mission(models.Model):
    taxi = ForeignKey(Taxi, null=True, blank=True, unique=True, related_name="mission")
    passenger = ForeignKey(Passenger, null=True, blank=True, unique=True, related_name="mission")
```

Now there's a method in the Class Taxi:

```
def turn_free(self):
    ....
    self.mission_set.clear()
    passenger.mission_set.clear() # passenger has been fetched
```

The first attempt to clear mission in Taxi proceed successfully, but the second one for the passenger reports an error: ccst_mission.passenger_id may not be NULL

Could someone help me?

Comment: Does the schema reflect the model accurately?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database has been updated properly.

For example, if you originally had (without specifying null=True)

```
passenger = Foreignkey(Passsenger, unique=True)
```

And added the null=True later on, a regular syncdb will not update that column to allow null.

If any of that sounds familiar, try doing an [sqlclear](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#sqlclear-appname-appname) on the app (or deleting the database entirely) then doing a fresh syncdb.